# Why do I see some questions with a blue background?

Tags: support, design, favorite-tags

I just noticed that in the "Questions" view, I see some questions with a blue background, e.g., the first one here:

[image: screenshot]

Is this some new feature?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This means that at least one of those three tags ([time-series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series), [arima](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arima) or [var](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/var)) were favorited by you. This feature facilitates users finding questions of their interest.

On the other hand, ignored tags makes questions labeled with them to appear with less visibility (shadowed?).

See the screenshot below. Just as an example, I added [repeated-measure](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeated-measure) as a favorite tag and [machine-learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) as an ignored tag.

[image]

Comment: Cool, thanks! I indeed just defined some favorite tags today and didn't connect the dots to the new appearance...

Answer (score 5):

+1 to @AndreSilva.  Specifically, on the right side of the screen / screenshot under the blue box you see "Favorite Tags".  Yours include [r](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r) [time-series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-series) [forecasting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forecasting).  Questions with those tags will be highlighted for you on most CV pages (if you go to the tag's page, it wouldn't be).  In your example, the highlighted thread is tagged with `[time-series]`.  Favorite Tags are added automatically by SE based on your pattern of answering questions.  If you don't want those threads highlighted, click the "edit" link next to Favorite Tags and add some nonsense (I have `[jkjkjk]`).